# Why did Umar forbid Mutah (temporary marriage) after the death of the prophet?(shia view)

Tags: sharia, history, shiism, nikah-al-mutah

In a famous sermon,the second caliph 'Umar banned mutah after the death of the Prophet (PBUH) with the following words:

> "Two mutah were practiced during the time of the Prophet [i.e.
>   temporary marriage and mutat al-hajj],but I forbid both of them and
>   will punish anyone who practices either."(**tafsir al-Razi,volume2,page167**)

You can see that in [al-islam](http://www.al-islam.org/muta-temporary-marriage-in-islamic-law-sachiko-murata/legitimacy-muta#2-sermon-umar) .

According to this evidence, what was Umar's reason for banning Mutah? (Shia view)

Comment: Mut'ah banned by Hazrat Umar and asking in Shia View. I am looking forward to the answer.

Comment: A related helpful complete site: http://www.al-islam.org/muta-temporary-marriage-in-islamic-law-sachiko-murata

Comment: **<closed>** As-written, this is attracting nothing but argument and opinion. And given the link in OP itself goes into far more detail regarding the Shi'a perspective than is even alluded to in the question, this doesn't appear to be an honest question at all.